# trigger returns dbo instead of sa

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

Why does USER_NAME(USER_ID())  returns dbo and not 'sa' as the
current username ?

I have a trigger that is supposed to insert the username
of the user making changes to the table.

However the trigger inserts dbo as the user.
Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using `suser_sname()`

and **STOP** using the `sa` login!!